# MetadataServerException when using GKE Workload Identity

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, google-iam

I am trying to enabled [Workload Identity](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#enable_workload_identity_on_a_new_cluster) on my cluster but I'm getting the following error when testing it from a pod:

```
root@workload-identity-test:/# gcloud auth list
ERROR: gcloud crashed (MetadataServerException): HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

I've enabled `workload-metadata-from-node`:

```
gcloud beta container node-pools update NAME --cluster NAME --workload-metadata-from-node=GKE_METADATA_SERVER
Updating node pool main...done.
```

Even if I add `--log-http` to the command it doesn't seem to show the request that's returning 500 (nor crucially, its response).

Any ideas? (I get the same error on a new cluster)

Answer (score 7):

**Update** I have been able to get this working with workloadIdentityUser since. I suggest following the delete-recreate tips outlined in [John's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58205952/1510063) if you still run into issues.

Based on errors logged by the `gke-metadata-xxxx` pod on the node where the test was running, I needed to use the `roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` instead of the `roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser` suggested in the tutorial linked above.

This allows me to use the feature as expected, however since the role is [not documented](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles) I'm not sure exactly what additional permissions I might have granted by making this switch.

Comment: I have also just encountered this issue, I also needed to enable "IAM Service Account Credentials API" for the project for this to work.

Comment: You can enumerate permissions using console: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/roles/details/roles%3Ciam.serviceAccountTokenCreator

Answer (score 2):

I was having an issue today about this. Everything was working fine using the roles (roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator and roles/roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser) and my Google Cloud Credentials API is also enabled.

If ever you encountered this problem again even after ensuring you have all the requirements above, delete the Kubernetes service account and create it again. You also have to restart the Pods that are using the service account so they can get the fresh service account token.

Finally, everything will start working again.

Answer (score 1):

`roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator` impersonates service accounts (create OAuth2 access tokens, sign blobs or JWTs, etc)
and `roles/roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser` impersonates  service accounts from GKE Workloads. Both roles are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#service-accounts-roles) and you can see the permissions each role has.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, but I could resolved it by just enable "IAM Service Account Credentials API" on the console.
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/iamcredentials.googleapis.com/overview

Answer (score 0):

So I was encountering the same issue, until I realised that I had forgotten to perform the annotation step to complete the binding.

The way I see it is that you need the following;

- roles/roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser

```html
gcloud config set project gsa_project
gcloud iam service-accounts add-iam-policy-binding \
  --role roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser \
  --member "serviceAccount:cluster_project.svc.id.goog[k8s_namespace/ksa_name]" \
  gsa_name@gsa_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

- iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account

```html
kubectl annotate serviceaccount \
  --namespace k8s_namespace \
   ksa_name \
   iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account=gsa_name@gsa_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

- IAM Service Account Credentials API